# VisualUpgrade doesn't fix all during 2010->2013 upgrade

Tags: 2013, upgrade, site-definition

**MY SOLUTION:**

I've found a solution for my problem. Before upgrade I've placed a special xml file in 15\CONFIG\UPGRADE folder, with information about my web templates, like this:

```
<WebTemplate ID="990001"
        LocaleId="*"
        FromProductVersion="3"
        BeginFromSchemaVersion="0"
        EndFromSchemaVersion="1"
        ToSchemaVersion="2">           
    </WebTemplate>
```

(But I had to duplicate such a node for both product version 3 and 4.)

After all, I've retracted my old 2010 wsp and redeployed my new 2013 solution. And in general it works.

**[UPDATED]**
My SharePoint solution contains a few custom site templates. After I performed a migration from SP2010 to SP2013, I still see that the migrated sites have a dependency on the SP2010 site templates. This is what I'm doing:

1. Created SP2013 farm and web application.
2. Deployed old WSPs (containing site templates for the SP2010 version)
3. Deployed new WSPs (containing the same site templates for the SP2013 version, with Revision property increased from 1 to 2)
4. Attached content databases from a SP2010 farm.
5. Mounted the DBs, which caused the content DBs to be migrated from SP 2010 to 2013.
6. Performed Visual Upgrade on site collections based on my custom site templates.

After that, the site collections are displayed with the SP2013 layout, which shows that the visual upgrade has been properly done. But, if I retract/remove the SP2010 WSPs I no longer can see the migrated site collections (I get a 404 error).

I’ve tried fixing the issue with the following approach.
1)  Changing the Revision attribute value from 1 to 2 in all onet.xml files of my own site definitions in \15 folder.
2)  Adding upgrade XML file inside the [15-hive]\Config\Upgrade folder:
3)  Executed “Upgrade-SPSite -Identity  -VersionUpgrade” in SharePoint PowerShell. In SharePoint log I could see entries related to the upgrade and that the created xml files were taken into account during upgrade.
4)  The issue can be fixed in a “dirty” and unacceptable way, by executing “update [dbo].[AllDocs] set [SetupPathVersion] = 15” on the SharePoint content databases, but of course it isn't acceptable.
I’ve did IIS resets multiple times at multiple steps, so the reason of this approach not working is not due to a missing IIS reset.

Do you have such an issue and know what to do with it?

P.S. Here is story similar to mine: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/02/file-not-found-error-after-upgrade-of.html 
But that solution didn't help me.

Comment: Did you not upgrade the solutions containing the site definitions to be compatible with SP 2013.

Comment: I've edited post with info that after content migration I've deployed new SP-2013-ready wsp with new site defs.

Answer (score 1):

I recently also did a migration of SP 2010 solutions which had site definitions. Following is my finding.

> Both versions of the site definitions (14 and 15) need to be present 
>   in respective hives at the time of performing upgrade. If either of
>   them is absent the above error will show up. I had deployed the
>   version 15 WSP using PowerShell commands: Uninstall > Remove > Add >
>   Install. This had removed the previous site definition files (onet and
>   template folder) from 14 hive and added latest files to 15 hive. When
>   I copied the old files to 14 hive, the upgrade worked.

See this for more info: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-following-sites-are-using.html

Comment: Yousuf, I've added info about steps to reproduce - sorry that my first post wasn't enough clear.

Comment: Error 404: did you check app pool in IIS. Make sure it is running

Comment: Here is a story of guy who had a same problem: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/02/file-not-found-error-after-upgrade-of.html